# IFS Bash Array - Comma separated

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

When I use `IFS=","` the comma is still included when printing array. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
group_list=("dummy group 1", "dummy group 2");
IFS=","
for i in "${group_list[@]}"
do
echo "$i - test";
done
```

Output:

```
dummy group 1, - test                -> How can I exclude the comma?
dummy group 2 - test
```

Comment: Don't put it there in the first place, in compound array declarations array elements are separated by spaces, not commas

Comment: I want to echo them as separated values so I can make use the values to pass to curl. But the comma is blocking me.

Comment: I can't use Space as the default since I have a JQ statement that needs comma in there. Once the JQ is done with that, I need to use the same array for curl

Comment: `"${group_list[@]//,/}"` and drop the `IFS`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 things:

- [bash array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)
- [bash internal field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)

If you like to use array:

```
group_list=("dummy group 1" "dummy group 2");
for i in "${group_list[@]}"
do
    echo "$i - test";
done
```

If you like to use bash separator:

```
group_list="dummy group 1","dummy group 2"
IFS=","
for i in ${group_list};     
do     
   echo "$i - test";     
done
```

Comment: I had to mix it because there was JQ command in between. `JQ` and bash `forloop` both used the same array. For JQ I needed a field separator other than default IFS space since the array contained value with space.

Comment: But @Jetchisel method works for now.  "${group_list[@]//,/}" and drop the IFS

Comment: @user: removing the comma in `("dummy group 1", "dummy group 2")` using `("dummy group 1" "dummy group 2")` works too, it avoid to add a comma and then remove it.